# Import tables structure and no data from one database to another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have database with multiple  tables in Microsoft SQL Server with schema in tables as "xyz".
i am able to copy this database tables along with data from one sql server to another using  export and import wizard of SQL server.

I want to do find a way to-
1. Copy only tables with no data.
2. is it possible to covert current database design to a script and then run the same on another server which will create all these tables with empty data ?
Thanks in advances.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do that with Management Studio. Right click your database and then select Tasks -> Generate Scripts. 
There are some settings there you should tweak, like if it should generate scripts for indexes and statistics. They are all in plain sight.

An alternative is [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx). It's relatively new (ex-Data Dude). It's not as straightforward, but better on a long term, for database versioning and for creating migration scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your quick reply